# Máscara de data para android

Tags: html, jquery, html5

Estou criando uma máscara em uma função no jQuery, porém no Android não funciona. No PC e no iOS funciona normalmente. Já fiz varias tentativas do que foram indicado nos fóruns, porém não obtive sucesso.

O interessante que antes funcionava, porém depois que inseri um popup nesta tela, a máscara parou de funcionar, mas não houve alterações na máscara. Poderiam ajudar por gentileza?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(".mascara").mask("99/99/9999");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: E quais tentativas você já utilizou? Já tentou [**depurar o site**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?hl=pt-br) e ver se aparece alguma mensagem de erro? Não funciona no navegador do *smartphone* ou não funciona na *WebView* de um app?

Comment: Tentei através de regex, porém sem sucesso. Não é possível depurar a aplicação devido as restrições do cliente. GEro o pacote e implanto para testar. Não funciona no navegador do smartphone.
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function mdata(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");                    //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1/$2");
    v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1/$2");

    v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})$/,"$1$2");
    return v;
        }
           </script>